# How to play (sound of) flv files in Foobar2000?

Tags: audio, flv, foobar2000

Given that Foobar2000 is one of the best audio players and that there are a lot of `flv` files  out there that are in fact mostly sound, and that Foobar already can play sound from `mp4` and `webm` video, it is not unreasonable to want to play them in this way, that is, to play the `AAC` sound contained in the `flv` movie.

Is there a foobar addon to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is Flash Video Decoder (`foo_flv.dll`), an addon that is not present on the main components page of Foobar2000.

I found about it in a comment [here](http://www.neowin.net/news/foobar2000-125-beta-1#comment-2165963) directing to [this](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=87021&start=0&p=818697&#entry818697) address.

The present latest version is [here](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=86913&pid=818695&mode=threaded&show=0&st=0#entry818695).

Here it is Foobar2000 playing a flv file (in Linux):

[image]

Comment: The official 0.91 links are down because there is [0.96](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=86913&pid=818695&mode=threaded&show=0&st=0#entry818695)